# Having trouble parsing a MySQL result in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to pull some results from a database but I guess I'm kind of brain dead today.

```
$castquery = "SELECT * FROM cast " .
    "WHERE player_id = '" . $userid ."' ";
$castresult = mysql_query($castquery) or die(mysql_error());
$castrow = mysql_fetch_array($castresult);
```

...

```
foreach($castrow['cast_id'] as $caster) 
{
    echo "<p>";
    if ($caster['avatar_url']!='') echo "<img src=\"".$caster['avatar_url']."\" alt=\"".$caster['name']."\">";
    echo "<a href=\"?edit=".$caster['cast_id']."\">".$caster['name']."</a></p>";
}
```

Surely I'm overlooking something obvious here.

Comment: How does the script fail, and what result are you trying to get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what your db structure is, but `$castrow['cast_id']` is a single field, not an array. What you probably mean is:

```
while ( $castrow = mysql_fetch_array($castresult) ) {
    // use $castrow array here
}
```

instead of your `foreach`

Comment: `castrow` should technically be called `castrows`, as it's the set of rows rather than one row.

Comment: Well, technically, every time you call `mysql_fetch_array()` you get *one* row, not many.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple and dumb.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code will only fetch one row as it is now.

```
$castrow = mysql_fetch_array($castresult);

foreach($castrow['cast_id'] as $caster) 
{
```

Should be

```
while ($castrow = mysql_fetch_array($castresult)) {

  $caster = $castrow['cast_id'];
  ....
```